# Redirect from indexed joomla URLS to static URL

Tags: .htaccess, static, joomla-sef-urls, redirect

I use to have a joomla site with SEF urls which are indexed in google like

example
www.mysite.com/index.php/contactme

i now have a static site and i want to 301 redirect my indexed urls to the the new one

example
www.mysite.com/contact-me.php

i have tried

Redirect 301 /index.php/contactme http://www.mysite.com/contact-me.php

but i get a internal server error. im complete novice at htaccess. i dont have the old joomla site any more only the static one

hope someone can help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your redirect is correct in the .htaccess. Maybe the problem is that Google didn't crawl your site again since you changed to the static site. Check in Google webmaster tools to make sure and make a manual crawl using the tools to determine HOW Google sees your site NOW. If it shows correctly then you'll just have to give the engine some time to recrawl and reindex your site.

Hope this helps

Comment: while the htaccess file is there i get internal error for all pages. am i better off not having the htaccess file

Comment: probably, try redirecting using a php script with Locate headers

Comment: i just tried header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/contact-me.php); i get nothing